# GAE - Inequality filters and cursors, they don't work together?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

There's some similar questions, but I couldn't find a concrete answer whether what I wanna do is possible or not. I'm using App Engine, JDO. I'm trying to retrieve the object "User" by doing the following query (also using cursors so that the same user is never "seen" again):

```
    .
    . *EDIT - added cursor-code*
    extensionMap.put(JDOCursorHelper.CURSOR_EXTENSION, Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorAsString)); //cursorAsString is retrieved from user
    Query query = pm.newQuery(User.class);
    query.setExtensions(extensionMap); //Contains the cursor object
    query.setRange(0, amount);
    query.setOrdering("bornYear asc, toc asc");
    query.setFilter("locationFid == :p1 && gender == :p2 && bornYear >= :p3 && bornYear <= :p4");

    List<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
    params.add(locationFid);
    params.add(lookingForGender);
    params.add(yearSpanStart);
    params.add(yearSpanEnd);
    results = (List<User>) query.executeWithArray(params.toArray())
    cursor = JDOCursorHelper.getCursor(results); //give this to user for use next request
```

In the documentation I can't seem to find anything saying it won't work using cursors and inequality filters only that it can behave strange (uhh?). But it seems it doesn't work in my case and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. The above code is "faulty" because it won't return "new" users added after the first request was made. However if I change the filtering and ordering to:

```
    query.setOrdering("toc asc");
    query.setFilter("locationFid == :p1 && gender == :p2");
```

The above will work, but then I won't be getting the age-span that I wanted. Is there some way to make the first version work? Or do I have to first retrieve the users without inequality, and then "manually" filter then server-side and then retrieve another "batch" if I didn't get enough results? This seem very bad, mostly because then the cursor will have moved passed these users and if I ever change the age-span, I won't be able to retrieve (/see) them again.

Thank you!

Comment: Take that warning not as just some strange things could happen, but as they will happen if you eventually get your code working. And once 'it's working' you'd have to come back to solve that. With Datastore you have to decide what you prefer to have: cursors or inequality filters. Pick one and implement a workaround of the another one.

Comment: Where do you set the cursor? It should be like this:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries#Query_Cursors

Comment: @PeterKnego Updated the question with how I use the cursors. As I said, the query works (with cursors as intended) if I don't use the inequality-filter. :/